# Core data and custom NSCell

Tags: memory-management, core-data, macos, nsarraycontroller, nscell

I am building a toy app using core data for two entities `Log` (attributes `text` and `date`) and `Tag` with a many-to-many `tags` relationship  from `Log` to `Tag`.

I want to show logs in a table, so I:

- created an `NSArrayController` instance, `LogController` in IB with entity set to `Log` ([pic](http://drp.ly/2bMas))
- created a one-column `NSTableView` whose column is bound to `LogController`. [pic](http://drp.ly/2bU3h)
- linked the `LogController` in my app delegate (`AppDelegate`) using `IBOutlet`. `AppDelegate` also has the `managedObjectContext`.
- created a custom `NSCell` class with `NSString` properties `mainText` and `tagsText` that I draw onto the cell
- I set the above two cell properties in `AppDelegate` in the `- (void)tableView: willDisplayCell: forTableColumn: row:` method. (`MainController` is also the table's delegate). For the `tagsText` I get the tags for the current log and concatenate them into a single `NSString`

Everything works fine, except: When I mouse-select a row that displays multiple tags the app crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. That's the only time I have any error, but I don't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is a memory error. You are using an object after deallocating it. It would be difficult to debug this without the code.

Are you using the garbage collector? You do not have to manage memory yourself on the Mac.

Are the properties in your custom NSCell declared as "retain"?

Comment: Right: I was not declaring one of the properties as retained. This solved it.